# Atom Editor: Fold selection onto single line

Tags: atom-editor

Is there a way in Atom to fold an entire selection on a new line? I'm trying to make a package that lets me select multiple lines of code and fold them. My markup would look something like this:

```
/* Text Colors */

.text-red {
    color: red;
}

.text-green {
    color: green;
}

.text-blue {
    color: blue;
}

/* Typography */

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

and then when I fold it, it would look something like this:

```
/* Text Colors */

[...]

/* Typography */

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

This way I can view looks of sections in my code at the same time. I've tried using `foldSelectedLines` but unfortunately that ends up folding it like this:

```
/* Text Colors */

.text-red {[...]

/* Typography */

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Where's the difference? Don't you think the initial tag (`.class` in your case) is providing valuable information? The current version also folds everything onto one line, doesn't it?

Comment: For example if there were 30 classes in Section 1 (which could be something like /* Footer */) and I selected them all and folded them all then the initial tag isn't really relevant(except to the first one), but I know what is in the selection based on the section comment. The current version always leaves the initial tag of a fold as far as I'm aware?

Comment: OK, understood. Maybe you want to update your example to show that there are multiple classes folded into a single line.

Comment: Have updated it now, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Its <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> on Linux & Windows or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> on mac.

Also in Atom press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> on mac) to open the command palette and type `fold` to get a list of all the possible fold options and related keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Ctrl Alt [ fold current row
Ctrl Alt ] unfold current row
Ctrl Alt f fold selection
Ctrl Alt Shift P log cursor scope
Ctrl Alt z checkout head revision
Ctrl Alt { fold all
Ctrl Alt } unfold all

Comment: Sorry I just realised I hadn't marked this is answered. I still find it odd that "Fold Selected" isn't under Edit > Folding like all the other fold commands.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - I wanted to fold arbitrary selections as in Textmate.

For Atom on the Mac at least ctrl-option-command-F works!